# How to upload Image to Worklight Server

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I am trying to build a worklight image upload app. I want to upload picture on Worklight server.
Is it possible. I am able to upload that image to test server using `ft.upload(imageURI, "http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=adsa", win, fail, options);`

But I want to know if I can upload that image on Worklight Server, If yes what would be the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not upload anything to the Worklight Server. The Worklight Server is more of a conduit, using adapters, between your application to your backend system - be it a files server or a database. For this purpose imagine your test server as the backend system.

Comment: Thanks Idan again for giving me right direction.
You are very quick in worklight.